# magento2 admin : generate controller url for form action

Tags: magento2, url, admin-controller

On a Magento2 admin page (order/view) I added a form using phtml file with block. I would like to define my form action to my controller url : `www.xxx.com/admin_toto/foo/bar/index`

How can I generate this url ?

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="<?php echo ADMIN_URL.'foo/bar/index'?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
    <input>...</input>
    <span><button type="submit">Update</button></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
$block->getUrl('foo/bar/index');
```